# How to join two collections A and B in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have two collections A and B and i want to join them with aggregate that the result will be object have information of collection A with matching information of Collection B if found

```
[{
   "id":123,
   "name":"abc"
},
{
   "id":124,
   "name":"abd"
},
{
   "id":125,
   "name":"abe"
},
{
   "id":126,
   "name":"abf"
}]


[{
   "id":098,
   "name":"xyz",
   "userId":123
},
{
   "id":098,
   "name":"xyu",
   "userId":123
},
{
   "id":098,
   "name":"xye",
   "userId":124
},
{
   "id":098,
   "name":"xyf",
   "userId":125
}]
```

result

```
{
   "id":123,
   "name":"abc",
   "data"[
      {
         "id":098,
         "name":"xyz",
         "userId":123
      }      {
         "id":098,
         "name":"xyu",
         "userId":123
      }
   ]
}, {
   "id":124,
   "name":"abd",
   "data":[
      {
         "id":098,
         "name":"xye",
         "userId":124
      }
   ]
}, {
   "id":125,
   "name":"abe",
   "data":[
      {
         "id":098,
         "name":"xyf",
         "userId":125
      }
   ]
}, {
   "id":126,
   "name":"abf",
   "data":[

   ]
}
```

Comment: You can try using the aggregation [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) stage to join the two collections A and B.

Comment: do you have any relation between two collections?